# Describing in English the operation that turns $a^2 \times b^2$ into $(a\times b)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

This is a very basic question but I could not find an answer for it.

When I turn $(a\times b)^2$ into $a^2 \times b^2$, I say : "I distribute the exponent over the multiplication"

But when I turn $a^2 \times b^2$ into $(a\times b)^2$, I'm not sure of how to describe the operation. I think "I group the bases together" would be sort of ok but I'm not satisfied.

Is there a way to say "I ??? the exponent"? I've never heard of anti-distribute, and maybe my english is not great but I would not use factor or condense here.

Thank you!

Comment: An all-use word is 'arrange'.

Comment: You are not using the distributive property, but rather that multiplication is associative and commutative.  What that means is that  $(a \times b) \times (a \times b) $ equals $a \times [ b \times (a \times b)]$ equals $a \times [(a \times b) \times b] $ equals $a \times [a \times (b \times b)] $ equals $(a \times a) \times (b \times b)$.

Comment: @user2661923 agreed but it's not convenient to mention that when going for a more visual description like when teaching high school. Distributing exponents is a term used in high school

Comment: @Trebor, do you mean sthg like " I arrange the exponents? "

Comment: If for a pair of operators  $(\phi,\gamma)$ that $(a\gamma b)\phi c = (a\phi c)\gamma(b\phi c)$ then we can say that $\phi$ distributes over $\gamma$, so saying that exponentiation distributes over multiplication is proper. Whereas the reverse is called "factoring" for the pair $(\times, +)$, I'm not sure that there is a set expression for doing the same thing with exponentiation and multiplication.

Comment: @John Joy, yes you said it well, I'm looking for a "set expression". I've spent months saying "the number inside the square root" before hearing of the word "radicand" by chance one day. So I'm thinking maybe there's a way to say "un-distribute exponent" but I've just never seen it!

Comment: @Albert Beton I know that "collecting like terms" is common in HS math class, so perhaps one could duplicate that language here. $2a+3a=(2+3)a$ seems analogous to $2^a\times 3^a = (2\times 3)^a$. Could we not say that we are "collecting like exponents"?

Comment: @JohnJoy, thank you for the suggestion. I think collect could work, something like "collecting the bases with like exponents" would be good to me and my students. Yet, I'll leave the post un-answered fot a bit, as I still wonder if there is a widely used set expression.

Comment: As long as you don't say "factorise out" the exponent....